# Failed to get access to the Internet after disabling networkmanager on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

How can I get access to the Internet after `networkmanager` is down? I disabled the `networkmanager` and uncommented the static IP settings I used to use and reboot, but I'm still unable to get access to the Internet. (Failed to `ping 8.8.8.8`, which means the problem isn't DNS.)

Here's how this happened:

I used to get access to the Internet on my ArchLinux machine by setting up a static IP address in `/etc/rc.conf`. This worked fine. Then one day I needed to do something difficult without a `networkmanager`, so I installed the `network-manager-applet` via `pacman`, which worked fine as well, until one day after I ran `pacman -Syu` and rebooted, many programs, including the `network-manager-applet` are unable to work, saying the system is missing `libpng14.so`. My workstation was connected to a wireless connection at that time (the same one before my last `pacman -Syu` and reboot), and I tried to run `pacman -Syu` again and the network seemed to still be working. So I didn't take it as a big problem at that time.

But now, after I brought it to work (where I connect to the Internet via a wired network and a static IP), I found myself unable to get access again to the Internet, even after I removed `networkmanager` from the `DAEMONS` in `rc.conf`, and uncommented the static IP settings that used to work. And It's not DNS problems since I'm unable to `ping 8.8.8.8` or any other known IPs directly (it says `destination host is unreachable`).

Here's my `rc.conf` files, the IP address and gateway stuff couldn't be wrong so hope you don't mind I use something like XX.XX.XX.XX instead:

```
LOCALE="en-US.UTF-8"
DAEMON-LOCALE="no"
HARDWARECLOCK="localtime"
TIMEZONE="Asia/Shanghai"
KEYMAP="us"
CONSOLEFONT=
CONSOLEMAP=
USECOLOR="yes"

MODULES=(wl)
UDEV_TIMEOUT=30
USEDMRAID="no"
USEBTRFS="no"
USELVM="no"

HOSTNAME="lastland"
interface=eth0
address=XX.XX.XX.XX
netmask=255.255.255.0
broadcast=XX.XX.XX.255
gateway=XX.XX.XX.XX

NETWORK_PERSIST="no"

DAEMONS = (syslog-ng network crond dbus kdm alsa)
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a dhcp client to get an address after connecting your media (wifi or cable)? dhcpcd or dhclient should do the trick, if you're lost check out your OS documentation (on their website).

Comment: can you ping your gateway? does the output of arp -na tells you something (can it resolve the gateway's mac?).

Comment: @Aki No, I can't ping my gateway.

Comment: @Aki No. We can only use static IP in our campus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that my eth0 MAC address isn't the right one. So I edit it, and problem resolved. Thanks @Aki for your help anyway.